# string handling in ksh

Tags: shell, scripting, ksh

I am writting small ksh script where i need to format the ldapsearch command using values of few variables and run that command to validate whether provided details of ldap server are correct. The script is failing for ldap user with space in it.

My script looks like something below

```
[root@c1n3 ~]# cat /tmp/test 
#!/usr/bin/ksh
set -x
username="CN=userwith space,CN=Users,DC=MYLDAP,DC=COM"
pswd="Passw0rd"
cmd="/usr/bin/ldapsearch -x -H ldap://192.168.1.2 -b dc=myldap,dc=com -s sub -o nettimeout=10 -LLL -A "
cmd+="-D $username -w $pswd"
cmd+=" (objectClass=*) -z1 dn"
print $cmd
retstr="$($cmd 2>/tmp/ldapfail.tmpwrite)"
ret=$?
print "retstr=$retstr"
print "ret=$ret"
print "/tmp/ldapfail.tmpwrite : "
[[ $ret -ne 0 ]] && print "ERROR:--------------" && cat /tmp/ldapfail.tmpwrite
```

Output of the above script

```
[root@c1n3 ~]# /tmp/test 
+ username=CN='userwith space,CN=Users,DC=MYLDAP,DC=COM'
+ pswd=Passw0rd
+ cmd='/usr/bin/ldapsearch -x -H ldap://192.168.1.2 -b dc=myldap,dc=com -s sub -o nettimeout=10 -LLL -A '
+ cmd+='-D CN=userwith space,CN=Users,DC=MYLDAP,DC=COM -w Passw0rd'
+ cmd+=' (objectClass=*) -z1 dn'
+ print /usr/bin/ldapsearch -x -H ldap://192.168.1.2 -bdc=myldap,dc=com -s sub -o nettimeout=10 -LLL -A -D CN=userwith space,CN=Users,DC=MYLDAP,DC=COM -w Passw0rd '(objectClass=*)' -z1 dn
/usr/bin/ldapsearch -x -H ldap://192.168.1.2 -b dc=myldap,dc=com -s sub -o nettimeout=10 -LLL -A -D CN=userwith space,CN=Users,DC=MYLDAP,DC=COM -w Passw0rd (objectClass=*) -z1 dn
+ /usr/bin/ldapsearch -x -H ldap://192.168.1.2 -b dc=myldap,dc=com -s sub -o nettimeout=10 -LLL -A -D CN=userwith space,CN=Users,DC=MYLDAP,DC=COM -w Passw0rd '(objectClass=*)' -z1 dn
+ 2> /tmp/ldapfail.tmpwrite
+ retstr=''
+ ret=49
+ print retstr=
retstr=
+ print ret=49
ret=49
+ print '/tmp/ldapfail.tmpwrite : '
/tmp/ldapfail.tmpwrite : 
+ [[ 49 -ne 0 ]]
+ print ERROR:--------------
ERROR:--------------
+ cat /tmp/ldapfail.tmpwrite
ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
additional info: 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment:  AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1
```

The ldapsearch command which is created in script is failing

```
/usr/bin/ldapsearch -x -H ldap://192.168.1.2 -b dc=myldap,dc=com -s sub -o nettimeout=10 -LLL -A -D CN=userwith space,CN=Users,DC=MYLDAP,DC=COM -w Passw0rd '(objectClass=*)' -z1 dn
```

if i escape the space using '\' like `CN=userwith\ space,CN=Users,DC=MYLDAP,DC=COM` on command line it works but it does not work in ksh script

script with `username="CN=userwith\ space,CN=Users,DC=MYLDAP,DC=COM"` also fails because script format the ldapsearch command in this way `/usr/bin/ldapsearch -x -H ldap://192.168.1.2 -b dc=myldap,dc=com -s sub -o nettimeout=10 -LLL -A -D CN='userwith\' space,CN=Users,DC=MYLDAP,DC=COM -w Passw0rd '(objectClass=*)' -z1 dn`

Any clue on how to fix this ?

Comment: could you try double backslash like "CN=userwith\\ space..." in script

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the command in an array. That way, any array elements containing whitespace will still be considered whole words.

```
username="CN=userwith space,CN=Users,DC=MYLDAP,DC=COM"
pswd="Passw0rd"

# build up the command as an array
cmd=( /usr/bin/ldapsearch -x -H ldap://192.168.1.2 -b dc=myldap,dc=com -s sub -o nettimeout=10 -LLL -A )
cmd+=( -D "$username" -w "$pswd" )   # variables must be quoted here
cmd+=( "(objectClass=*)" -z1 dn )

# print the contents, note the different outputs
print "${cmd[*]}"
printf "%q " "${cmd[@]}"; echo

# execute it
retstr="$("${cmd[@]}" 2>/tmp/ldapfail.tmpwrite)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this in your script;

```
LDAPHOST="ldap://192.168.1.2"
username="CN=\"userwith\ space,CN=Users,DC=MYLDAP,DC=COM\""
pswd="Passw0rd"
cmd="/usr/bin/ldapsearch -x -H "${LDAPHOST}" -b dc=myldap,dc=com -s sub -o nettimeout=10 -LLL -A "
cmd+="-D "${username}" -w "${pswd}" (objectClass=*) -z1 dn"
echo $cmd
```

Comment: it still fails with \\  `/usr/bin/ldapsearch -x -H ldap://192.168.1.2 -b dc=myldap,dc=com -s sub -o nettimeout=10 -LLL -A -D CN='userwith\' space,CN=Users,DC=MYLDAP,DC=COM -w Passw0rd '(objectClass=*)' -z1 dn`